# How to make a widget in the center of the screen in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

This code works, but I wonder if there is any simpler way:

```
def center(self):
    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = gui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Comment: This seems about as right as you can get it to me.

Comment: A nice snippet from ZetCode. I wondered if there was some shorter way, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's the simplest way. Here is a snippet I've used in C++:

```
  QRect desktopRect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(this);
  QPoint center = desktopRect.center();

  move(center.x() - width() * 0.5, center.y() - height());
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `frameGeometry()` like in OP's code instead `width()` and `height()`([Qt. Window Geometry](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry))

Answer (score 20):

just add this line to your main windows :

```
self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- self.rect().center())
```

Answer (score 9):

```
self.move(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center() - self.frameGeometry().center())
```

Comment: I changed the second argumento to make it more centered.

Answer (score 2):

Just another "func-style" example. If you use it several times.

```
screen_center = lambda widget: QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- widget.rect().center()
```

And every time in code:

```
widget.move(screen_center(widget))
```

Answer (score 2):

QDesktopWidget is deprecated. Use QScreen instead.

```
    def centerWidgetOnScreen(self, widget):
        centerPoint = QtGui.QScreen.availableGeometry(QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()).center()
        fg = widget.frameGeometry()
        fg.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        widget.move(fg.topLeft())
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication

# ...

    def center(self):
        centerPoint = QGuiApplication.screens()[0].geometry().center()
        self.move(centerPoint - self.frameGeometry().center())
```